# Are the extra 6 movepoints of Human Musketeer compared to Ballistae worth it?

Tags: age-of-wonders

Human Musketeer is a Lvl 3 unit (Ballista is Lvl 2, thus requires fewer upgrades and less time to produce) that costs 45 gold to produce (OK, Ballista costs 64, 19 more) and upkeep is 8 (for ballista it is 6). Ballista has 2 more HP than the Musketeer (7 vs. 5). It becomes less severe with level-ups, but because Ballista is Lvl. 2, it requires less XP to level up.

Shoot Javelin ability, [as you can see in the table I have made](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rASjl3jrVAPkXxxAapBi6SvXNNthcJLDHDBD9t4oJhM/edit#gid=51767927), deals around 1.5 times more damage per round than the Fire Musket ability. It becomes worse with time because Ballistae level up faster, requiring less XP and inflicting more damage.

The only real reason to produce a Musketeer, as I see it, could be the move points: it has a speed of quick infantry (28), while the Ballista has a speed of a machine (20), which is very slow. However, if I want speed, I have Human Cavaliers available in the same race on the same level.

So, **Is there any reason to produce Musketeers?**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, musketeers are one of the absolutely pointless units in the game. He is basically an archer with a better ranged attack and when you can have a unit like the cavalier, what reason is there to produce an archer?

The musketeer is squishy, helpless in melee combat and his ability isn't very strong. This is not what you want and need from a tier 3 unit. Just give them a wide berth.

Comment: Agree, especially when the alternative is cavalry which is a hardhitting strong unit.